# Data structures to Implement Hierarchical clustering

Tags: memory-management, data-structures, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

If I were to implement a Hierarchical clustering algorithm, say in C/C++ or Java - given the functions for computing distance between& within  clusters -

**1**.  what would be my choice(along with other options) to **implement the data structures** on storing the results of the computed clusters in each "pass" from the proximity metric which is defined as n^2 below.

> ```
>         Corresponding Proximity matrix
>    p1 p2 p3 p4 .... and hence n*n 
> p1 d11 d12 d13 d14
> p2 ...
> p3...
> p4 ...
> ```

**2**. Would the choice of data structures **differ if I were to use top down as opposed to bottom up** building of the corresponding dendograms?

[image]

An example of bottom up dendogram(source, Wiki)

**3.** Since the problem of computing the clusters & the centroid thereof is **computationally intensive**(Greedy algorithm ?) - will this get better with the choice of data structures- what are the abstract choices that you can think of ?

**4.** Is there really such a thing as **sparse matrix** [post having calculated the proximity of 2 points, which then grow on to assimilate more neighboring points, there will be less points, if we were to store our "new" distances  in a new matrix] in this context ? 
**Will the data-structure shrink/grow wrt this need ?**

**5.** Can this matrix exist **in memory**, or parts of the cluster thereof - If not, what do we have to re-load into memory before computing every next cluster (agglomerative clustering, or otherwise)

*+1 if you stick with a conceptual(& hopefully intuitive) answer/or redirect me in that direction*

PPS : I don't NEED a function to help me implement this - *just want to understand* this from a memory management & conceptual point of view wrt large datasets. I have very little knowledge on this subject, so ignore if this sounds too primitive .

Comment: Maybe you could 1. be more specific 2. point out, what you are actually trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at Slink algorithm paper by R.Sibson , It defines a data structure called PointerHierarchy using which you could cut the dandogram at a given distance to arrive at clusters. This algorithm doesnt need you to prepare a similarity matrix ahead which would reduce the memory footprint. The paper also gives a sample implementation in FORTRAN which you could easily write in language of your choice. I have used this method in my production code in java and results have been quite good.